# Want to use selected values from extended choice parameter in Jenkins using multi-level parameter type in bash

Tags: jenkins, extended-choice-parameter

[Inputs from the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAbKo.png)

I want to use the seleted values one by one in bash script.
Also want to save these values in a file.
How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get there, try to write a [Jenkins Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/). You need to use those parameters in your [Jenkinsfile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/). Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392247/how-can-i-use-the-extended-choice-parameter-plugin-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-script) to see how to use the extended choice parameters in your jenkinsfile.
You are able to pass those parameters to your bash script inside your Jenkinsfile. Also, using bash script, you can insert them in a file as well.

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730186/jenkins-extended-parameter-plugin-groovy-script) as well. It gives some insight into how this works.